# Laravel - Select / join friends to posts table

Tags: laravel

I'm pretty new to laravel and the SQL statements, and I'm trying to get the posts to show or load posts for both the logged in user and his friends.
The posts table has an author_id, and the friends table has sender/recipient/status
Where the sender or recipient can be the current logged in person and where the status is 2 (Accepted)
Currently I have this

```
@foreach(Friends::where("sender", "=", Auth::user()->id)->orWhere("recipient", "=", Auth::user()->id)->where("status", "=", 2)->get() as $friend)
@foreach(Posts::where("author_id", "=", Auth::user()->id)->orWhere("author_id", "=", $friend->recipient)->where("relation", "=", "feed")->orderBy('post_time', 'DESC')->orderBy('post_date', 'DESC')->get() as $post)
```

Could someone please tell me or show me how I could join the posts/friends and have one loop to show the content from both mine and my friends accounts.

Comment: The logic for this should be hidden behind a method inside of the model, and I suggest using Eloquent relationships to handle this. There are a few mappings here you could make, one to many for user relationships, then one to many for user posts

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help

```html
@php

$friendsPosts = Friends::where("sender", "=", Auth::user()->id)
                    ->orWhere("recipient", "=", Auth::user()
                    ->id)->where("status", "=", 2)
                    ->with([ 'posts' => function ($query) {
                        $query->where("relation", "=", "feed")
                            ->orderBy('post_time', 'DESC')
                            ->orderBy('post_date', 'DESC');
                    }])->get();
                            
@endphp

@foreach ($friendsPosts as $post)

<!-- code inside the loop -->

@endforeach
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that although ran into this `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::Posts() (View: /var/www/dev-facesmash/app/views/home.blade.php)`

Answer (score 0):

I would continue with the answer of @tirta, please confirm that you do have a relation named 'posts' in the 'Friends' Model thereby establishing a relation between 'Friends.php' and 'Posts.php'.